# Async method in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a problem with sending email with method annotated as @Async.
Firstly, I am not sure if it is possible to work as I want so I need help with explanation.

Here is what am doing now:

In main method i have annotation

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Next I have AsyncConfig class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurerSupport;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("email-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Of course, its rest application so i have controller, service etc, looks normally, nothing special

My async method looks like this:

```
    @Async
    public void sendEmail() throws InterruptedException {

        log.info("Sleep");
        Thread.sleep(10000L);    
        //method code
        log.info("Done");
    }
```

I executing this method in another service method:

```
@Override
    public boolean sendSystemEmail() {

        try {
            this.sendEmail();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.info("pending sendEmail method");
        return true;
    }
```

Now what I want archive is to ignore executing `sendEmail()` function and execute `return true;` meanwhile function `sendEmail()` will be executing in another Thread. Of course it doesn't work now as I want. Unfortunately.

Note that I am new into async programming, so I have lack of knowledge in some parts of this programming method.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ah the classic error/misunderstanding. For async processing spring uses AOP. AOP is applied using proxies, which means only calls INTO the object will get AOP applied. You are doing a method call from inside the proxy. You need to call `sendMail` externally and not internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First – let’s go over the rules – @Async has two limitations:

it must be applied to public methods only
self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn’t work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async